# API-PLATFORM User Update Password Or user profile

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I need help :-D, I'm a beginner on Symfony and Api Platform. I have an entity User, I want create an items Operation for update my user with an object `{ email: string; firstname: string; lastname: string }` without password, and a second itemsOperation just for my password.

I have testing, but I can't do it.

this is my entity user and annotation api.

```
/**
* @ApiResource(
*      itemOperations={
*          "get",
*          "update_password"={"method"="PUT", "path"="user/{id}/update-password", 
*          "validation_groups"={"updatePassword"}},
*          "update_user"={"method"="PUT", "path"="user/{id}/update-user", 
*          "validation_groups"={"updateUser"}}
*      }
* )
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
      */
     private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min="8", max="22")
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"updatePassword"})
     * @Assert\IsNull(groups={"updateUser"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Groups({"updateUser"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"updateUser"})
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"updateUser"})
     */
    private $lastname;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
    
        return $roles;
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        $this->password = null;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(?string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

If I used update-user endpoint, failed error because i not send my password.

Can you help me?

Thanx all.

Answer (score 3):

The "Symfony way" to handle this, is using 2 fields: `password` and `plainPassword`. This is Symfony best practice in general.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"user"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\Listener\Entity\UserEntityListener"})
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password; // This field should NEVER be exposed.

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min="8", max="22") // Apply validation here, not on $password
     * @Groups({"user"}) // Expose using groups
     */
    private $plainPassword;
```

Next, create an entity listener (or any api platform event listener) to change `password` if `plainPassword` is not empty.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listener\Entity;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface

class UserEntityListener
{
    private UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
    ) {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdateHandler(User $user): void
    {
       if ($user->getPlainPassword() !== null) {
            $password = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want different `itemOperations` to change password, you can still do so by changing the groups.

Comment: `plainPassword` should NOT be a column! Never store plain text passwords in a database!

Comment: @lxg whoops, I copied $password. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Are the `@ORM\PrePersist()`/`@ORM\PreUpdate()` annotations/attributes supposed to register the listener automagically? From the documentation, it seems that these annotation are supposed to be declared directly in the entity.